# Mileage Charge calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Been keeping track of mileage for multiple vehicles which have limited mileage on.

The company we lease the vehicles from have `2` different charge rates for over mileage fees.

Anything less than `10000` miles is charged at `17p` per mile, anything over is then charged at `70p` per mile.

The spreadsheet I use, calculates mileage left available so anything over the mileage limit becomes a negative number; `-500` as an example.

I have tried the following IF statement

```
=IF(J28<-10000,J28*0.17,((J28+10000)*0.7)+1700)
```

which for a `-8000` value in `J28` is giving `3100` as the result but it should be `-1360`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's -10000 coming from in the condition?

Comment: Is your source data `Current Mileage`, and the calculation occurs?  Seeing a negative value sounds like you're inputting `Miles til High Price Rate`.

Comment: Your first condition says if `J28<-10000` but -8000 is not smaller then -10000.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

=IF(-J28<10000,J28*0.17,(-(J28+10000)*0.7)+1700)

Comment: That worked for the -8000 value but when inputing -12000 value it gave 300 as the end value when it should be 3100.

Comment: What it is happening that the condition is -8000<-10000 which is False and will jump to the False part of the IF function so, I just changed the values in the condition to be 8000<10000 and it worked fine. But you still to do further testing to be sure that it is working with all cases.

Comment: =IF(-J28<10000,J28*0.17,(-(J28+10000)*0.7)+1700)

Comment: Again you need to test the formula to be sure it is working for all scenarios

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work for those values.
Thank you so much.